# How to get data from request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, fetch

My project is bundled on webpack (localhost:9000). I did post request to other local server(localhost:3000), now I need to take this data on localhost:9000/etc. I tried to do get request on localhost:3000, but it is not correct. Explain me please, what I have to do?

my request

```js
function getReq() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/test')
    .then(response => {
   response.json();
})
  .then(data => {
    // Work with JSON data here
    console.log(data.body);
  }).catch(err => {
    // Do something for an error here
    console.log("Error Reading data " + err);
  })
}

getReq()
```

My server(I need to send req.body)

```js
    app.post('/post',(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
        app.get('/test',(request,response)=>{
            response.send(req.body)
        })
    res.send('ok')
})
```

Comment: Why is `app.get` is inside `app.post`?

Comment: For the `fetch` request you forgot to `return response.json()`. For the server see what @Dijkstra said...

Comment: @Dijkstra post request on /post doing from localhost:9000, on localhost:9000/order I need to take req.body from previous request, so I did get request on /test, where sent req.body